# how do I remove ./ from the file name

Tags: shell, shell-script

How do I remove `./` from the file name `./script 1` when entering it as a command. I want to be able to enter the command just as `script 1` for it to run?

Comment: Okay, you _can_ add `.` to your `$PATH`. But don't do this, it's an obvious security flaw (which is why this is no longer done). Typing the extra two characters really isn't _that_ hard.

Answer (score 4):

The `./` is not part of the filename, it is necessary to tell your shell that 
it should look in the current directory for the command `script`.

If you do not provide that your shell (assuming `bash` or `sh`) will only look in the directories specified in `$PATH`. So either move your `script` in one of those directories, or extend the $PATH with the directory in which `script` is located.

I have my "own" scripts and programs in `/home/anthon/bin` and this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -d /home/anthon/bin ] ; then
    PATH=/home/anthon/bin:"${PATH}"
fi
```

so that this directory is automatically added to each `bash` shell I start.

If that is impossible you can define an alias:

```
alias script='./script'
```

But of course **that** only works if you in the directory and if not gives you:

```
bash: ./script: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can also do `export PATH=$PATH:.` to be able to execute anything in the current directory. However this is not the best practice.

Comment: @jgr208 You can, but you shouldn't, as HalosGhost commented on your question. It is a security flaw. You should organise your scripts in a bin directory, or if you can't use `alias script='./script'`.

Comment: yup, that is why I said not a best practice. In my early linux days I used to put the current directory in my path. Now I am used to typing the ./ or if it is that needed a lot like you said put it in a bin directory and add that directory to my path.

Comment: @jgr208 Sorry, I did not read properly and  I thought you were the OP asking for confirmation if (s)he should do this.

Comment: No worries, I have read things plenty of times wrong here